# Run AndroidStudio project ignoring some irrelevant errors

Tags: android-studio

In AndroidStudio, is it possible to run a project which has files containing errors but which are not necessary in the pipeline of the project? In particular, we have two MainActivity.java scripts which test different things but I would like to run only one of them, letting the other one be (even though it may include some errors).